# Varnish. How can I ignore url special parametrs to return cached but leave the query string origin?

Tags: nginx, varnish, devops

Varnish. 
How can I ignore url special parametrs  to return cached but leave the query string origin?

```
domain.com/?utm1=232&urm2=2323
```

I need leave this utm for GA, but ignore to return cached page.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a header with the relevant url to cache and change the way varnish hash the objects.

```
sub vcl_recv {
  ...
  # Remove the params you don't want from the query string and set it to a 
  # temp header (Varnish does not have variables)
  set req.http.x-cache-url = regsub(req.url,"(utm1=.*&|utm1=.*)", "")
  ...
}

# Below is the default vcl_hash but swapping the req.url for req.http.x-cache-url
sub vcl_hash {
  hash_data(req.http.x-cache-url);
  if (req.http.host) {
    hash_data(req.http.host);
  } else {
    hash_data(server.ip);
  }
  return (lookup);
}
```

Doing that you will be able to maintain your query string as it is and you'll still be able to deliver the same cache for different params.

**Note** that the *regsub* is where you manipulate the params. Feel free to change according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to rewrite the incoming URL and not introduce unnecessary VCL. This will also take care of all Google related Javascript variables, not just utm_ones:

```
if (req.url ~ "(\?|&)(gclid|utm_[a-z]+)=") {
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(gclid|utm_[a-z]+)=[-_A-z0-9\+\(\)%]+&?", "");
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "(\?|&)$", "");
}
```

See more in my original post on [stripping Google Analytics variables with Varnish](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/varnish/strip-query-parameters-varnish).